# Ruby on Rails vs Parse + Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parsing, backbone.js

I started making my app last year, but have recently had that **HOLY** **** moment where I realized that going into developing a serious web app with PHP just won't cut it nowadays with regards to scalability and overall sanity.

This lead me to the following options:

1. Rewrite my backend in the most beautiful MVC available - 37Signal's **Ruby on Rails**
   or
2. Scrap my database and rewrite my backend in **Backbone.js + [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)**

([Parse just released their web SDK](http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/30/parse-launches-javascript-sdk%3a-parse-for-websites/))

I'm no history buff, but hear me out here. PHP lead web development until recently. Now Rails is taking over. This alone would make most people pick Option 1. However, what if Parse takes over Rails like Rails took over PHP? I'm planning for the future, and I'm beginning to think that Parse is the way of the future.

**What should I rewrite my app in to maximize scalability for years to come?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is the way of the future. Everything in **one** language without having to worry about the backend. Engines that mimic Parse will be the best free alternative, although I think we can all take the example of Apple and understand that software people pay for is software better maintained.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Rails developer and love Rails, but I don't think, that Rails "took over" PHP in any form. There are still plenty of sites in PHP. PHP, it's frameworks and everything around it are flourishing as ever. And will be for quite some time to come.

Ruby on Rails has established a strong position and community. This too will last for many years to come. Backbone will most likely find it's community too (already has to some extend)

A decision about a technology should not regard much which technology stack will be the new kid on the block. There are some considerations, like availability of experienced programmers, that may depend on how much used a framework is, but hard facts about you technological needs are far more important. There shouldn't be any "holy" moments about this. That's just gut feelings and worth nothing.

Comment: What it comes down to is: what's **easier**? And fact is: Rails. That's why Rails is getting the hype over any PHP framework. PHP frameworks are very flawed from my experience, especially when it comes to HABTM relationships.
However, now there's a new breed out there. Parse is a pioneer. You didn't really touch on it, but I think I've made my decision to take a walk on the wild side.